# I am not able to install PyAutoGui

Tags: python, pyautogui

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMG04.png

```
C:\Windows\System32>pip install pyautogui
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process 
using '"C:\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe" 
install pyautogui': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've tried installing PyAutoGui for a while now, but this error keeps appearing.

I have tried **reinstalling Python**, but that didn't work.

The version of Python I am using is **3.10.2**.

I am using **Windows 11 Home Insider Preview Single Language**.

Comment: Can you please share the exact screenshot of an error?

Comment: The screenshot of the error is the imgur link.

Comment: You must have a macro or batch file defined that redefines the `pip` command.  Do `doskey /macros` to check that.  You can always do `python -m pip install pyautogui`.  Are you running in an elevated command session?  Why?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to work with python is to create virutal environment for an application and then you can install any module with pip install <module_name>
Please follow this link
https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/